# Cookie values are coming up as cookie name in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, cookies

I have been wondering why my application has been allowing duplicate votes for a while and finally debugged the issue.

When you vote you get a cookie named "vote" and the value is the ID of the "thing" you voted on.

```
Cookie voteCookie = new Cookie("vote", "1901");
voteCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365);
response.addCookie(voteCookie);
```

I checked the client (Chrome) and there is a cookie named "vote" with the value "1901"

When I then read this cookie in my Spring Controller like this:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

I now have two cookies:

```
CookieName: ["vote"] Value: [""]
CookieName: ["1901"] Value: [""]
```

The other cookies like JSESSIONID are correct:

```
 CookieName: ["JSESSIONID"] Value: [000046KQaPe3T8gwXVuB3zhNrON:-1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Turns out there was some code that appended the old value with the new one:

```
voteCookie.setValue(voteCookie.getValue() + "," + cookieValue);
```

And this seems to be what caused the problem. The value after the "," (comma) became another cookie with that name. I'm not sure if this is a WebSphere Application Server issue or what. But changed the delimiter to "-" and everything works!

Comment: I feel there's more to it than `new Cookie("vote", "1901");`. Can you post the actual code that invokes this constructor?

Comment: As well as the code that enumerates the cookies.

Comment: Looks like the cookie is being added to the response, so that's not it…

Comment: @adarsh you're right, there was some code that appended the old value with the new one. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem was due to commas in the value of the cookie. There are some references to the javadoc in this question: [Cannot get value from cookie in Java. Value contains colons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227576/cannot-get-value-from-cookie-in-java-value-contains-colons)

I changed the delimiter to "-" and all is good